# Python muddling up file paths

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I am running the program shown below in python 2.7 and it is adding extra slashes to the file path. Why is it doing it and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
key = raw_input('Please enter encryption key path: ')
print key
akey = open(key, 'r')
```

What I get when I run it:

```
Please enter encryption key path: C:\\OCryptosoft\key.oekey
C:\\OCryptosoft\key.oekey
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Oscar Hill\Desktop\OCryptosoft\decrypt\decrypt.py", line 81, in <module>
akey = open(key, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\OCryptosoft\\key.oekey'
```

Comment: is a file path starting c:\\ legal to start with on windows ? It could be that given an illegal path the open function is further breaking the file path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426606/tony-suffolk-66. The file path I used is not legal on windows - I need to use C://OCryptosoft/key.oekey

Comment: While it certainly isn't common to use multiple slashes there on windows, it does work when I test it in my python 2.7.7 environment.
@Oscar_Technologies I literally duplicated your explanation (right down to creating the directory/file and pasting in the input you were using) and had no problem on a windows machine.